# display:inline doesn't work work with border

Tags: html, css

I encountered a problem when I tried to put 2 divs next to each other.

`display: inline` it deletes my border and doesn't place both divs on the same line.

Please advise:

```css
.gig {
    outline: 1px solid green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="gig">
    <h3>The band</h3>
    <p><em>We love to play</em></p>
    <p>Great gigs we have met good people!</p>
</div>
<div class="gig">
    <h1>great shit</h1>
    <p>fdfdsfsd</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ideally, `<h1>` would come before an `<h3>`. If you're looking to re-size text, consider using a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these changes:

Use float:

```
float: left;
```

or

```
float: right;
```

Or use display inline:

```
display: inline-block
```

or use flex display:

```
display: flex
```

Comment: i managed to arrange the divs on the same row using flex.  now  I don't get how to have other divs in a second row. Every div i add now squeeze with the others on the same row.

Answer (score 1):

`Inline` objects doesn't have height or width property, so use `display: inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
float: left;
```

instead of

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to **block** elements, **inline** elements don't have properties such as width, height, margin, etc.

**Solution:**

use `display: flex`

> **For cross-browser support:**
>
> use `display: inline-block`

Comment: thanks to everyone! display:flex helped the most, it arranged my divs on the same line and it didn't cancel my border. i put all my divs under one container and wrote the css display:flex at the container only.